# XSS Attack Prevention

Tags: scripting, xss, cross-site

I have a web application written in PHP. The templating engine is SMARTY. My question is very simple, yet the answer should not be that easy, because I searched the hell out of it to no avail.

When I telnet to port 80 and run the following command:

```
GET /some_directory_on_my_server/?""><SCRIPT>alert(123)</SCRIPT>
```

The servers responds back with an html page. When I save this HTML page and open it in a browser I see alert(123) on top of the page, which means that the site is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

My question is how can I access the **actual url** entered by the user in order to sanitize it? When it comes to user input sanitization for **forms** or **database queries**, the scenario seems to be much easier, because you actually have a variable on hand to manipulate, but in the case of **actual url** entered by the user in a browser, how can I get hold of the **url** itself to sanitize it?

For your information, I have already read all modules which provide library functions for XSS Prevention, but none gives me an example on how to deal with **actual url** XSS Attack. By the way, my `magic_quote_gpc` in my php configuration is already turned off. What should I do now? Any thoughts?